# Assuming that for every integer $n>1$ there is a prime between $n$ and $2n$ prove that every positive integer can be written as sum of distinct primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Note that in this problem 1 is treated as prime

My proof goes like this(not complete)

Let say we want the number $q$ to be written as sum of primes.$q$ may be even or odd.First consider the case when q is even.

By assumption there is a prime say $p_1$ such that

$\frac{q}{2} <p_1<q$ now we should add $q-p_1$ to $ p_1$
to get $q$ notice that $q-p_1$ is odd

Then there is a prime number say $p_2 $ such that

$\frac{q-p_1-1}{2}<p_2<q-p_1$

If now$ p_1+p_2 = q$ we stop here other wise we continue this process.one more step if $p_1+p_2$ not equals to $q$.

Then there is a prime say p_3 such that

$\frac{q-p_1-p_2}{2}<p_3<q-p_1-p_2$

We continue this process untill we get to $q$.Notice that at each step value is decreasing $p_1>p_2>p_3$ so this process terminates at some point. We can do the same when q is odd.This completes the proof.

Is this proof legit or there are any holes in it??I showed that this process terminates  but I am not able to show that we actually end up with $q$

Comment: Yes, but usually one use induction to get a cleaner proof! Something like: suppose that this holds for numbers from 1 to n-1. Now we show the thesis for n. You find the first prime p, then you know that n-p= sum of distinct primes. You are left with proving that the primes you use for n-p are distinct from p (something that maybe you didn't show in your proof).

Comment: Can you send the proof?? (in you way)

Answer (score 2):

We will prove the OP thesis by induction on $n \ge 2$.

Base case: $n=2,3$ are primes and thus trivially true.

Inductive step:

Suppose the thesis is true for $1,\ldots, n-1$. We want to show it for $n$ (recall that $n\ge 4$ cause we have checked smaller cases).

There exist a prime $p$ such that $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor <p \le n$. Now $n-p$ is smaller then n and greater than 2, so by inductive hypothesis it can be written as $\sum q_i$, where $q_i$ are distinct primes. Suppose $q_i=p$ for some i. Then

$$ p=q_i \le \sum q_i = n-p$$
Implies $p\le n/2$. But p is an integer, so $p\le \lfloor n/2 \rfloor < p$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: It is clean by induction